# ASP.NET Dynamic Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic

I can't find solution for my problem.
I'm making web shop.
I have list of products which i'm taking from database. I'm sending all of them to html with foreach

```
<% foreach (var product in productList) { %>
            <h1><%= product.Name  %>  &nbsp;
```

I want to have button "Buy Now" for each of products and after clicking want to have id product property in sender.
What would be best way to do that ?

Comment: This code is a bit outdated. Why not using server side controls?

Answer (score 0):

Generate buttons with different IDs & properties that result in the same OnClick method in the code behind.

In the code behind:

```
// Generate elements for each product  
foreach (var product in productList)  
{  
   Button btn = new Button();  
   btn.CommandArgument = product.ID; // This would be your product ID  
   btn.Text = "Buy Now";  
   btn.Click += Btn_Click;  

   this.Products.Controls.Add(btn);  
}
```

In the markup:

```
<div id="Products" runat="server">
</div>
```

Or either use a WebHandler (.ashx) which acts as an endpoint to retrieve a request and process to return data. Helpful for async as well.

Comment: But how to put into asp:Button's ID property from "product" ?

Comment: Generate your buttons in the code behind instead of in the markup, and use the `CommandArgument` property to set it to the product ID value. Then in the click event you'll get the event sender.CommandArgument value

Comment: and how to send each button for each product in html?

Comment: Something.Controls.Add is obly avaible for asp elements. div isn't asp's. Is there alternative for div  ?

Comment: That's not true. because runat="server" you can dynamically add elements exactly how it's stated in my answer.

Comment: But you can use any element of your choosing. You do not have to use `<div>` if you don't want to.